# Is it safe to go to Turkey in 2017?

Tags: safety, turkey

This question was [asked before](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19442/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-turkey-at-this-time-august-2013), but now things may be different because a few years have passed.

Particularly, I am interested in going to [Nesin Mathematics Village](http://matematikkoyu.org/eng/), near Sirince.  I would be coming from the US and returning there afterwards.

Comment: *Is-it-safe-to...*-type questions are hard to answer without you specifying what you consider as safe and what not, i.e. what you are concerned about. See [Personal Safety post on Meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1906/32134). Voting to close as unclear / opinion-based until you specify.

Comment: Şirince and surrounding area are considered very safe. If you are a first-time visitor, I should warn you against the traffic terror (as we call it). Especially in the big cities, traffic runs very different from the western counterparts. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_traffic-related_death_rate, deat rate per vehicles is twice the European rate...

Answer (score 6):

Since some time there are diplomatic struggles between Turkey and several western countries, the riot that started yesterday between the Netherlands and Turkey could have its implications and spread to further conflicts between the EU and Turkey, so it is wise to follow the news the coming time to make a conscious decision. This is still the latest up to date advise but since you are not going to the south east, should be fine :) Keep in mind that per 21 july 2016 the state of emergency is in place.

Generic:

- Be alert when travelling and do not go to crowds and very busy places. Follow the latest news of the embassey. In the whole country on a regular frequency political demonstrations take place that can end in violence and riots.
- There are risks for travel in Turkey, travel in south east Turkey not after sundown on the road. If you happen to be in an accicent with "deaths": the police will take everyone in custody even if you are not guilty. Because of the emergency identity checks and traffic checks take place, so always have your papers at hand
- Do not travel to the border area with Syria and Iraq. Do not go to the city Diyarbakir. Only travel to the south east provinces when absolutely necessary
- Criminality is equal to Southern Europe countries. In larger cities and tourist centra more criminal activities occur. Especially around Istanbul these seem to increase
- In the whole country there is a heightened risk for terrorist attacks
- Keep in mind local laws and customs
- register yourself with the embassey then the embassey can reach you when there is an emergency situation
- refrain from making political statements, the current leadership has already purged or imprisoned 100.000 regime critics including public figures, journalists, academics, intellectuals, human rights activists even young children

***update*** since about 10 minutes travel advice for netherlands has been adjusted to a higher risk. http://www.nu.nl/reizen/4536312/reisadvies-turkije-aangepast-diplomatieke-spanningen.html

Answer (score 0):

What risk are you talking about? Spillover from the Syria conflict? Political unrest and terror? The recent spats with the rest of Europe?

On average it seems as safe as [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_in_Chicago#Annual_murder_totals_in_Chicago_by_year). Would you consider that city too dangerous?

Comment: Actually, yes, I consider Chicago too dangerous. And this answer seems more heavily weighted toward _comment_ than _answer_...

Comment: I mean, last year there was a terrorist attack at the airport and a failed coup. That's not to say such things will or will not happen again, but these are low-frequency, high-impact events far more likely to impact travelers than Chicago, where the problem is mostly gun crime far away from the average visitor getting deep dish pizza inside The Loop. How someone ranks those will, of course, depend on their personal preferences for risk.

Comment: I am confused. Is Chicago prone in frequent terrorist attacks? Including the airport? Was there any public unrest+attempted coup? I fail to see where this parallelism comes from?

Comment: @PsySp, for the victim it doesn't matter if it was a terrorist or criminal attack. I'm talking about roughly equivalent per-capita numbers of deaths.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Turkish citizen living in Istanbul. I can say that it is pretty safe over here in all Turkey. You can travel without any hesitation. Sirince is a great village, I've been there, really good local wines also.